# Why is __dirname not defined in node REPL?

Tags: node.js

From the node manual I see that I can get the directory of a file with `__dirname`, but from the REPL this seems to be undefined. Is this a misunderstanding on my side or where is the error?

```
$ node
> console.log(__dirname)
ReferenceError: __dirname is not defined
    at repl:1:14
    at REPLServer.eval (repl.js:80:21)
    at Interface.<anonymous> (repl.js:182:12)
    at Interface.emit (events.js:67:17)
    at Interface._onLine (readline.js:162:10)
    at Interface._line (readline.js:426:8)
    at Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:603:14)
    at ReadStream.<anonymous> (readline.js:82:12)
    at ReadStream.emit (events.js:88:20)
    at ReadStream._emitKey (tty.js:320:10)
```

Comment: `__dirname` and `__filename` are also [not available when `node` is called with the `--experimental-modules` flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46745014/alternative-for-dirname-in-node-when-using-the-experimental-modules-flag).

Comment: I got this issue when using eslint, I had mistakenly set `"browser": true` instead of `"node": true` in my .eslintrc.json file.

Comment: If nothing works here's a hack https://stackoverflow.com/a/49879107/696535

Answer (score 236, accepted):

`__dirname` is only defined in scripts. It's not available in REPL.

try make a script `a.js`

```
console.log(__dirname);
```

and run it:

```
node a.js
```

you will see `__dirname` printed.

Added background explanation: `__dirname` means 'The directory of this script'.  In REPL, you don't have a script.  Hence, `__dirname` would not have any real meaning.

Comment: Also you can't use some of the Global variables inside RequireJS modules. If you use RequireJS on the server side, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9027429/how-to-use-nodejs-global-module-objects-in-requirejs-modules.

Comment: Yeah, that should really be added to the answer Eye, because that's what got me.

Comment: Not adding that in to the REPL's load script is obnoxious. I can't think of any reason it wouldn't be there...

Comment: I loaded a script file while inside the REPL using `.load script.js`. It's too bad __dirname still isn't available from within script.js

Comment: upvoted! saved me 15 mins as I was wondering wtf is happening

Comment: this just restated the question without answering it

Answer (score 340):

If you are using **[Node.js modules](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html)**, `__dirname` and `__filename` don't exist.

From the [Node.js documentation](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v15.x/api/esm.html#esm_no_require_exports_or_module_exports):

> **No require, exports, module.exports, __filename, __dirname**
>
> These CommonJS variables are not available in ES modules.
>
> `require` can be imported into an ES module using [`module.createRequire()`](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_createrequire_filename).
>
> Equivalents of `__filename` and `__dirname` can be created inside of each file via [`import.meta.url`](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_import_meta):

```
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
import { dirname } from 'path';

const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = dirname(__filename);
```

https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v15.x/api/esm.html#esm_no_filename_or_dirname

Comment: Technically this is the only correct answer here. All of the other solutions use the current working directory. Which is different from the __dirname feature that is really the folder holding the currently running script.

Comment: This is the perfect answer for this exact question. Thank you, it helped me a lot! @RaviLuthra is 100% correct.

Comment: Concurr this is the only correct answer here "if" problem is relating to  ES6 modules type of architecture. Import statement needs to reference path that evetnually gets passed downt to __dirname which is the feature that is really the folder holding the currently running script. –

Comment: Obviously `import.meta.url` is `undefined` when `cat script.js | node --input-type module`

Comment: REPL context is *not* ES module. This answer is completely missing the point of the original question. import.meta is inaccessible from a REPL context as @SaberHayati mentioned, and this answer does not work at all. I don't know why it's getting so many upvotes.

Answer (score 173):

Building on the existing answers here, you could define this in your REPL:

```
__dirname = path.resolve(path.dirname(''));
```

Or:

```
__dirname = path.resolve();
```

> [If no `path` segments are passed, `path.resolve()` will return the absolute path of the current working directory.](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/path.html#path_path_resolve_paths)

---

Or @Jthorpe's alternatives:

```
__dirname = process.cwd();
__dirname = fs.realpathSync('.');
__dirname = process.env.PWD
```

Comment: if you use `nesh` you can define this as part of your load script; it's nifty

Comment: or `__dirname = process.cwd()` or `__dirname=fs.realpathSync('.')` or `__dirname = process.env.PWD`

Comment: `path.dirname` seems to not accept non-string values anymore in the newest major version, `6.0.0`, so the first suggestion in this answer will not work.

Answer (score 69):

In ES6 use:

```
import path from 'path';
const __dirname = path.resolve();
```

also available when node is called with `--experimental-modules`

Comment: You don't need to import core modules in the REPL; it will load them on the fly for you.

Comment: This gives the current working directory, not the directory of the current `.js` file.

Comment: @Dirbaio, what would be the _current `.js` file_ when you're in the REPL?

Comment: @c24w just checked, it seems to give the CWD

Comment: @Dirbaio I think that was my point.  When you enter the REPL, there is no current JS file.  What would you want `__dirname` to be, if not the CWD?

Comment: This is wrong. `__dirname` is meant to be current modules directory, but your solution makes it current working directory. How did this nonsen get so many upvotes is beyond my understanding.

Comment: path.resolve() is the root dir of the project or CWD, it is not __dirname

Answer (score 21):

-> At ES6 version use :

```
import path from "path"
const __dirname = path.resolve();
```

-> And use it like this for example:

```
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname ,'views','shop.html'))
```

Comment: This is **NOT** equivalent to `__dirname` but rather `process.cwd()`. For example, you will get different results when running the script from different directories. When using ESM a better approach is to use `import.meta.url`. See 
https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v14.x/api/esm.html#esm_import_meta
and
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46745014/alternative-for-dirname-in-node-when-using-the-experimental-modules-flag

Comment: This worked for me inside a docker. Thanks

Comment: does it works with browser?

Answer (score 7):

As @qiao said, you can't use `__dirname` in the node repl. However, if you need need this value in the console, you can use `path.resolve()` or `path.dirname()`. Although, `path.dirname()` will just give you a "." so, probably not that helpful. Be sure to `require('path')`.

Answer (score 7):

I was also trying to join my path using `path.join(__dirname, 'access.log')` but it was throwing the same error.

Here is how I fixed it:

I first imported the *path* package and declared a variable named `__dirname`, then called the `resolve` *path* method.

In CommonJS

```
var path = require("path");

var __dirname = path.resolve();
```

In ES6+

```
import path  from 'path';

const __dirname = path.resolve();
```

Happy coding.......

Comment: I am on node v15.3.0 and I do not need to use `path.resolve()`. `__dirname` just works out of the box. Is your answer still relevant to ES6+?

Comment: @Zac __dirname is only available on Node 14 or higher if you are using CommonJS. But ECMA is pushing towards ES modules being the standard instead of CommonJS.

Answer (score 4):

If you got `node __dirname not defined` with `node --experimental-modules`, you can do :

```js
const __dirname = path.dirname(import.meta.url)
                      .replace(/^file:\/\/\//, '') // can be usefull
```

Because othe example, work only with current/pwd directory not other directory.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like you could also do this:

```
__dirname=fs.realpathSync('.');
```

of course, dont forget `fs=require('fs')`

(it's not really global in node scripts exactly, its just defined on the module level)

Comment: You don't need to require core modules in the REPL; it will load them on the fly for you.

Answer (score 3):

I was running a script from batch file as SYSTEM user and all variables like `process.cwd()` , `path.resolve()` and all other methods would give me path to C:\Windows\System32 folder instead of actual path. During experiments I noticed that when an error is thrown the stack contains a true path to the node file.

Here's a very hacky way to get true path by triggering an error and extracting path from e.stack. Do not use.

```
// this should be the name of currently executed file
const currentFilename = 'index.js';

function veryHackyGetFolder() {
  try {
    throw new Error();
  } catch(e) {
    const fullMsg = e.stack.toString();
    const beginning = fullMsg.indexOf('file:///') + 8;
    const end = fullMsg.indexOf('\/' + currentFilename);
    const dir = fullMsg.substr(beginning, end - beginning).replace(/\//g, '\\');
    return dir;
  }
}
```

Usage

```
const dir = veryHackyGetFolder();
```

Comment: If you're not running this through the REPL, you _can_ use `__dirname` and `__filename`.

Comment: This is the only answer that at least tries to provide correct solution.

Comment: @c24w I tried __dirname, __filename and everything else. No standard solution worked in my case. Here's my project which runs a process as SYSTEM from task scheduler if you're bored github.com/DVLP/Unscheduler. Any standard solution that otherwise works is obviously better than my hack above :)

Answer (score 2):

Though its not the solution to this problem I would like to add it as it may help others.

You should have **two underscores** before dirname, **not one underscore** (`__dirname` not `_dirname`).

[NodeJS Docs](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#globals_dirname)

Comment: __dirname (with two underscores) does not work in the REPL

Answer (score 0):

This is a workaround, but it works both in CommonJS and in ESModules. This can be used so far NodeJS is in a crisis due to the transition from CommonJS to ESModules. I have not found other ways. `import.meta.url` cannot be used, because TypeScript files will cease to be compiled in CommonJS.

**__filename.ts**

```
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url'

export function get__filename() {
  const error = new Error()
  const stack = error.stack
  const match = stack.match(/^Error\s+at[^\r\n]+\s+at *(?:[^\r\n(]+\((.+?)(?::\d+:\d+)?\)|(.+?)(?::\d+:\d+)?) *([\r\n]|$)/)
  const filename = match[1] || match[2]
  if (filename.startsWith('file://')) {
    return fileURLToPath(filename)
  }
  return filename
}
```

**code.ts**

```
if (typeof __filename === 'undefined') {
  global.__filename = get__filename()
  global.__dirname = path.dirname(__filename)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All in one solution, for handling cases of js, mjs, cjs files existing inside a single project and errors from bundlers.

```
import { fileURLToPath } from "url";
import { dirname } from "path";

function getScriptFileAbsolutePath(importMeta) {
  try {
    return { __dirname, __filename };
  } catch (e) {
    if (!importMeta?.url) {
      throw new Error("bad importMeta");
    }
    let __filename = fileURLToPath(importMeta.url);
    let __dirname = dirname(__filename);
    return { __dirname, __filename };
  }
}

console.log(getScriptFileAbsolutePath(import.meta));
```

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that there were no errors generated by either typescript or eslint about this in my ESM project. Adding the following to my eslint config fixed this:

```json
{
  rules: {
    // Disallow commonjs globals
    "no-restricted-globals": [
      "error",
      { name: "__filename" },
      { name: "__dirname" },
      { name: "require" },
      { name: "module" },
      { name: "exports" },
    ],
  }
}
```