# How to use NodeJS global module objects in RequireJS modules

Tags: node.js, requirejs

I decided to use RequireJS as my module loader in NodeJS.

Unfortunately, the modules I define don't have access to some of the "global" objects that would be be available if the modules were loaded using the CommonJS method.  This includes the objects that are located in the module scope, such as `__dirname` and `__filename`.

Is there a relatively simple approach to using these objects in the RequireJS modules?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is covered on the requirejs issues site on github (https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/issues/89) and the workaround they seem to suggest is to use module.uri instead.

Comment: Thanks, here's the relevant content from that post:
<blockquote> jrburke commented April 09, 2011 </blockquote>
b> If you do the following, you should be able to get the path and dir> for the current module:
{{{
define(['module', 'path'], function (module, path) {
    console.log("module's path is: " + module.uri);
    console.log("module's dir is: " + path.dirname(module.uri));
});
}}}