# Use __dirname into class compiled in Typescript AMD

Tags: requirejs, typescript, amd, dirname

I'm looking for a solution to use __dirname (or equivalent) inside a TypeScript class compiled in AMD, __dirname doesn't exists there. And because it's typescript, I can't (or I don't know how) import `module` that contains `uri`, allowing me to get the uri.

I found the solution once, but I don't remember how and I can't find it again so far.

I took a look to this, but it's in pure javascript and I use typescript, I tried to import module, but I get a TS error.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9027429/how-to-use-nodejs-global-module-objects-in-requirejs-modules

Comment: Normally, I'd expect it to be in a definitions file of some sort. But, you could just add: `declare var __dirname: string;`

Comment: But __dirname will be empty if I do that. I need to have access to the path of the current directory

Comment: At runtime, it won't be empty. It just acts as a placeholder for the compiler.

Comment: Ok, I think you don't understand, but I didn't say it actually.
I use requireJs, which remove the __dirname, __filename nodejs globals, they are not avalaible inside the requirejs module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to:

In app.js, create a global var:

> __basePath = __dirname;

Then, in the AMD script, use `__basepath + 'relativePathFromBasePath'` to load the file.

I know I found another solution but I cannot remember how.

Answer (score 0):

I do not use TypeScript, but on the basis of the TypeScript code I've seen and on the basis of what I know of RequireJS, I believe you should be able to access `module.uri` like this:

```
import module = require("module");
console.log(module.uri);
```

The name `module` is [special](https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/wiki/Differences-between-the-simplified-CommonJS-wrapper-and-standard-AMD-define#wiki-magic). You could also use `require.toUrl(<module name>)` (that's `Url` as in URL whereas the variable above is `uri` as in `URI`) but it does not seem as useful as `module.uri` for this task. For one thing you'd have to include the module's name in the call.

`module.uri` may contain `..`, so it needs cleaning up. I understand your code to be running server-side, so in Node.js we'd call `path.dirname(path.normalize(module.uri))`.

Comment: I tried, but my IDE couldn't find the "module" library and I got IDE errors and the .ts was not compiled into .js anymore. :/

Comment: Can you access `require.toUrl`? I don't like it as much because you have to pass the module's name, but it would work.

Comment: Yes, I have access to `require` becuse it's automatically imported with requirejs!

Comment: I asked whether you have access to `require.toUrl`, not just `require`. As I understand it, TypeScript could give you access to `require` but such that the `toUrl` function is not visible to TypeScript code.

Comment: I'm currently working on another issue, and because of this issue I don't use AMD by now, until I find a solution, so I can't really test it now, but I'll update this thread when I'll find a solution. The issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21506083/load-scripts-with-requirejs-issue-with-absolute-path