# Load scripts with requireJs, issue with absolute path

Tags: javascript, requirejs, typescript, amd, commonjs

I'm trying to load scripts using requireJs() function, based on requirejs.

Here my app.js:

```
// Other stuff...
__config.path.base = __dirname + '/../';
requireJs = require('requirejs'),// To use to require AMD typescript files.
requireJs.config({
    baseUrl: __config.path.base,
    nodeRequire: require
});
```

But I got an issue... This script isn't app.js actually, it's /config/boostrap.js, now, if I want to import a file in the file `/api/db/models/UserModel.ts`, the path is actually `'/$APPPATH/'` instead of `'/$APPPATH/api/db/models/'`

So, when I try to import, from /api/db/models/**UserModel.ts**:

```
import model = require('./Model');
```

It fails, because it tries to load the file `'/$APPPATH/Model.js'` instead of  `'/$APPPATH/api/db/models/Model.ts'`.

If I try to import differently like that:

```
import model = require('./../api/db/models/Model');
```

Typescript display an error and doesn't compile anymore, because it cannot find the file.

So, how can I fix this? My solution here was to change the compilation mode and don't use requireJs to load file into /api (CommonJs), but I'm not sure I won't have other problem later, I would prefer use the same compilation mode everywhere if it's possible!

Comment: Is this supposed to run in Node or something? In a browser, I'm pretty sure `__dirname` is not defined.

Comment: Yes, server side only here!

Comment: If you are running in Node - why not load everything using CommonJS loading instead? (i.e. tell the TypeScript compiler you are using CommonJS - you don't need to change any code). Your `import x = require('y');` statements will then use Node's built-in module loader.

Comment: I know that. The fact is I will have issues if I try to make inheritance or dependencies betweens scripts compiled in differents mode (AMD & CommonJS) because I use both and I need AMD, so I would have prefered use only one to avoid this kind of problem.

Answer (score 0):

Typescript's import statement (using requireJS) will always use your application root path for the start point, as will the compiler.

From /api/db/models/UserModel.ts:

```
import model = require('api/db/models/Model');
```

Make sure Model.ts is structured like...

```
class Model {
    ...
}

export = Model;
```

Comment: Your solution use CommonJS compilation and the path would fail too. Because the IDE use the path it knows, relative to the current folder.

Comment: that's not my experience with VS2012 and TS 0.9.1.1  All my require statements follow the format above and, regardless of the position of the files relative to each other, the TS compiler will correctly find all modules.

Comment: I use WebStorm as IDE. I'm pretty sure this kind of path won't work.