# How do I reliably reference "node_modules" from package.json scripts?

Tags: npm, npm-scripts

The postinstall stage for my package.json uses `tsc`.  I'd like to make it so such a global dependency is never expected of the user, and the solution is to replace it with `./node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc`.

Unfortunately, this only works if `node_modules` is a subfolder of the one I'm currently in.  So what I would like to do is use some form of env variable which probably exists but I can not find to do this:

`$ROOT_NODE_PACKAGE/node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc $CURRENTLY_INSTALLING_PACKAGE`

How do I do this?

Comment: The documentation says "Since the module lookups using `node_modules` folders are all relative, and based on the real path of the files making the calls to `require()`, the packages themselves can be anywhere.", I think this technique would work, no? https://stackoverflow.com/a/12239689/3196753