# Force npm test to make fresh\new copy of input

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine, mocha.js

```
test/
├── TestOne.js
└── TestTwo.js
```

Say, `TestOne.js` is :

This test case reads from file `InputOne.json` and add one record to the object which already has 3 records.

```
describe('Add Items', function () {
      it('Should add items', function () {
       var input = require('./data/InputOne');
       var obj = new Department();
       var result = obj.AddDept(input);
       result.should.have.length(4);
      });
   });
```

Say, `TestTwo.js` is :

This test case reads from file `InputOne.json` and count the no of elements

```
describe('Count Items', function () {
      it('Should count items length', function () {
       var input = require('./data/InputOne');
       var obj = new Department();
       var result = obj.CountDept(input);
       result.should.have.length(3);
      });
   });
```

**Problem:**

Both the test cases uses same file as input. If I run test cases using mocha both the test cases passes

`mocha TestOne`   // Passes

`mocha TestTwo`   // Passes

if I say `npm test` (which runs all the test cases) I get error as test case in TestOne file has modified the input file. How I can make test case not to cache input file (or force test case to create its own copy of input file)

Answer (score 0):

To ensure the file is always loaded in its current form from disk, load it with `fs`:

```
var fs = require('fs');

var input = fs.readFileSync('./data/InputOne');
input = JSON.parse(input);
```

http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_filename_options

Comment: I am trying to make use of the code you suggested but i ran into another problem: this is the code I am using now to read file: `var input = fs.readFileSync('./Specs/queries/inOne.json');
    input = JSON.parse(input);`  Now when I say `npm test` system runs test case but when I say `mocha TestOne` I get following error `no such file or directory c:\testcase\specs\Specs\Queries\inOne.json`

Comment: How I can ensure both the commands uses the same path. When i use mocha it is automatically appending `specs` folder

Comment: @PUT_OR_POST See `__dirname`: http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#globals_dirname

Comment: Thanks for quick help but looks like I cannot use `__dirname` in my code. See this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8817423/node-dirname-not-defined