# Using the Node REPL to log the value of __dirname

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-repl

If I write a script like containing `console.log(__dirname);` logs the value of `__dirname`.  But if I try the same for the Node REPL like this happens:

```
 > console.log(__dirname)
 ReferenceError: __dirname is not defined
```

Thoughts?

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8817423/node-dirname-not-defined

Comment: That's essentially what I always do, since the REPL always seems like it does not quite do what I want it to do, so I've just given up on it essentially, but I figured it's been a while and maybe it's gotten better ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this [What is the difference between __dirname and ./ in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8131344/what-is-the-difference-between-dirname-and-in-node-js#18283508) written by [d512](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1334007/d512)

> In Node.js, `__dirname` is always the directory in which the currently executing script resides (see this). So if you typed `__dirname` into /d1/d2/myscript.js, the value would be /d1/d2.

The documentation says that `__dirname` is equal to `path.dirname`. If you type `path.dirname` into the repel it tells you this:

```
> console.log(path.dirname)
[Function: dirname]
undefined
```

Now my guess is: Since it is a repl, you don't have a file which is stored somewhere on the disk. It simply reads the command, evaluates it and prints it to the console.

Someone with more experiences on REPLSs might give a longer and detailed answer, but I think this laid out the concept.