# __dirname is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, google-cloud-platform

I don't understand why my `Google Cloud Run` instance doesn't know what `__dirname` is

I have an expressjs server that has this in it:

```
import path from 'path';

const App = express()
    .get('/*', (_req, res) => {
      res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '.', 'index.html'));
    })
```

I get a compile error `__dirname is not defined`

Comment: Did you look at answers to this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8817423/8483196?

Comment: __dirname is only available in script files save with .js ext

Comment: this is a js file, it's expressjs.  https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec

Comment: I should be at least able to do `console.log(__dirname);`

Comment: would really like to see the error stack. Can you post it?

Comment: it's in google cloud when it tries to run my container that has this expressjs code in it, I pasted the exact error as the title of this thread

Comment: What's your node version?

Comment: the latest, that's not the problem...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Rename to __dirname  it should be point to `path.join(__dirname, './src'),` or you can create using `const __dirname = path.resolve(path.dirname(''));`

Comment: `path.resolve(path.dirname(''))` produces the current working directory, not the directory the file resides in.

Answer (score 3):

```
    const path = require('path');
     
    import { fileURLToPath } from 'url'
    
    const __filenameNew = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url)
    
    const __dirnameNew = path.dirname(__filenameNew)
```

you can use __dirnameNew instead of __dirname in ES module

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.