# Getting error "Path" argument must be string while deploying React - Loadable components sample code in cloud functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, google-cloud-functions, loadable-component

I'm trying to integrate Loadable components in my SSR project and that is working when I executed in localhost:3000, then I tried to deploy it in cloud function I am getting this error

> [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received undefined

After that I tried to deploy [loadable components server side rendering example](https://github.com/gregberge/loadable-components/tree/main/examples/server-side-rendering-async-node), sample code also giving the same error.

I did some changes in package.json, server main.js and app.js file to work in Cloud functions

**This is my server main.js file**

```
import path from 'path'
import express from 'express'
import React from 'react'
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server'
import { ChunkExtractor } from '@loadable/server'
import App from '../client/App'
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const app = express()


//app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../../public')))


const nodeStats = path.resolve(
  __dirname,
  '../../public/dist/async-node/loadable-stats.json',
)

const webStats = path.resolve(
  __dirname,
  '../../public/dist/web/loadable-stats.json',
)

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  const nodeExtractor = new ChunkExtractor({ statsFile: nodeStats })
  const { default: App } = nodeExtractor.requireEntrypoint()

  const webExtractor = new ChunkExtractor({ statsFile: webStats })
  const jsx = webExtractor.collectChunks(<App />)

  const html = renderToString(jsx)

  res.set('content-type', 'text/html')
  res.send(`
      <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
        <head>
        ${webExtractor.getLinkTags()}
        ${webExtractor.getStyleTags()}
        </head>
        <body>
          <div id="main">${html}</div>
          ${webExtractor.getScriptTags()}
        </body>
      </html>
    `)
})

// eslint-disable-next-line no-console
exports.supercharged = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

In this file I did these changes from example code `app.listen` to `exports.supercharged = functions.https.onRequest(app);` and I imported the `const functions = require('firebase-functions');`

**This is my package.json file**

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon src/server/main.js",
    "build": "NODE_ENV=production yarn build:webpack && yarn build:functions",
    "build:webpack": "webpack",
    "build:functions": "babel -d functions src",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production node functions/server/main.js",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions,hosting",
    "serve": "firebase serve --only functions,hosting"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/core": "^7.6.2",
    "@babel/node": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.6.2",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "@loadable/babel-plugin": "^5.10.3",
    "@loadable/component": "^5.10.3",
    "@loadable/server": "^5.10.3",
    "@loadable/webpack-plugin": "^5.7.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "css-loader": "^2.1.1",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.6.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.19.0",
    "webpack": "^5.0.0-beta.16",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.2",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^3.6.2",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^1.7.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.0.1",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "firebase-admin": "^9.2.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.11.0",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6"
  }
}
```

In package file I replaced babel script to copy files to functions folder instead of lib

```
"build:functions": "babel -d functions src",
```

**Here is my app.js**

```
import React from 'react'
// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-extraneous-dependencies
import loadable from '@loadable/component'

const App = () => (
  <div>
  Hello world
  </div>
)

export default App
```

Loadable componets has lot of code in app.js so I just replaced app.js with simple hello world text

**Here is my firebase.json file**

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "function": "supercharged"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

These all are the changes I made from the the [loadable-components server side rendering async](https://github.com/gregberge/loadable-components/tree/main/examples/server-side-rendering-async-node) node example

I don't know what I missed here, Please assist me if I missed or need to add anything

Comment: what node version you are using? This may happen if node version is less than 10.0.0

Comment: I'm using 14 ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check by downgrading webpack to 4.31.0, Loadable components has some issues with webpack 5

```
"webpack": "^4.31.0",
"webpack-cli": "^3.3.2",
"webpack-dev-middleware": "^3.6.2",
"webpack-node-externals": "^1.7.2"
```

Answer (score 1):

From my reading of the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v14.x/api/path.html#path_path_resolve_paths) for path it is unnecessary to provide `__dirname` to `path.resolve()`. It will resolve the absolute path for any given relative path including if no parameters are given.

```
path.resolve(); // => '/root_path/current_working_directory'
```

With a relative path:

```
const location = path.resolve('./your_relative_path/file.json')
// OR
const sameLocation = path.resolve('./your_relative_path', 'file.json')
// => '/root_path/current_working_directory/your_relative_path/file.json
```

Exceptions to this rule are where you enter a non relative/absolute paths as parameters. Then it will attempt to resolve the path right to left until a valid path is formed:

```js
path.resolve('/your_absolute_path/file.json')
// OR
path.resolve('/your_absolute_path', 'file.json')
// => '/your_absolute_path/file.json'

path.resolve('/your_absolute_path', '/file.json')
// => '/file.json'

path.resolve('/one_path', '/another_path', 'file.json')
// => '/another_path/file.json'
```

So, your resolved code should look as follows:

```
const nodeStats = path.resolve('../../public/dist/async-node/loadable-stats.json')

const webStats = path.resolve('../../public/dist/web/loadable-stats.json')
```

This will give you `/Volumes/React-Project/SSRAsync/public/dist/async-node/loadable-stats.json` and `/Volumes/React-Project/SSRAsync/public/dist/web/loadable-stats.json` respectively. This still holds true through to Node 16.x

Answer (score 0):

As @hilipati has pointed out, `__dirname` is not defined. But there is a more simple solution to that issue, found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28279609/8020389)

Before using `__dirname`, you can overwrite the default behaviour like

```
if(!__dirname) {
    __dirname = path.resolve(path.dirname(''));
}
```

or, alternatively

```
if(!__dirname) {
    __dirname = path.resolve();
}
```

Comment: No __dirname has this value "/Volumes/React-Project/SSRAsync/functions/server"