# What is [eval] in context of __filename?

Tags: node.js

I wanted to see what filename would be returned when I pass the argument __filename to the node binary. In result I was expecting to see the node binary's path which would be evaluating the command but I got the following result:

```
node -p __filename
[eval]
```

What is [eval]? How do I interpret it?

My node version is as follows:

```
node --version
v14.17.4
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval

Comment: Why should an eval object be a __filename?

Comment: Because you are in REPL. What else sould be `__filename` set to? Same for `__dirname`, that is set to `.` Should it be undefined? That would break things.

Comment: Let us have a look at the __filename documentation at https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_filename . It is supposed to be "The file name of the current module. This is the current module file's absolute path with symlinks resolved." so if [eval] is the module performing the REPL we should be expecting its file path.

Comment: Eval is not a file/module, its a built in js function. Therefore it has no filename/path. Its just a mocking, so you dont break things.

Comment: The expected output is the absolute path of the module and not a function name.

Answer (score 0):

See https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#__filename

You should use it in your script

script.js:

```js
console.log(__filename);
```

then run:

```bash
node script.js
```

It will print actual full name of script.

When one does

```
node -p 'console.log(__filename)'
[eval]
undefined
```

The __filename cannot be defined, as there is not script file.
Maybe node.js has eval() functions that, that get the filename value.
But in some case it fails, or is not called.

Also see [Why is __dirname not defined in node REPL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8817423/why-is-dirname-not-defined-in-node-repl)