# Why are __filename and __dirname not available in ES modules?

Tags: node.js, es6-modules

I'm aware that, when using ES modules, `__filename` and `__dirname` don't exist.

This is clearly stated in [Node.js documentation](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v15.x/api/esm.html#esm_no_require_exports_or_module_exports), and also alternatives can be found in several places, like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62892482/14752499).

What I'm missing here is the cause of this behavior. *Why* are these variables not available in ES modules?

I could not find an explanation on SO or in the Node docs.

Answer (score 2):

When re-using the same code between a browser, Node.js, d8, Babel, etc., the notion of what the filename is and what it means may be different based on how you're using it, and where the file is being served from.  Filenames may not be relevant the same way when served from a webserver or when packed by a bundler, or interpreted by a shell.

And so in an effort to standardize this across those "platforms", ES modules come from URLs not filenames, and `import.meta.url` exists as replacement functionality.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use more ES6-standard ways of doing things because those are more likely to exist on other platforms too like Deno and Bun and the browsers. '__dirname' and '__filename' are very Node.js specific.